# jQuery Datatables webforms call

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I am trying to use Datatables within my webforms application.
unfortunatly I get the whole html page instead of json data :'(
this is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#grid').dataTable({
            "dataType": 'JSON',
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": 'GategoriesManagement.aspx/GetPersonList',
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aoColumns": [

                            { "sName": "d.name" },
            ]

        });
    });

</script>
```

my webmethod

```
  [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string GetPersonList()
    {
        List<personne> personeList = new List<personne>();

        personne person = new personne();
        person.name = "test1";
        personeList.Add(person);

        person = new personne();
        person.name = "test2";

        person = new personne();
        person.name = "test3";

        personeList.Add(person);
        FormatedList list = new FormatedList();

        list.iTotalDisplayRecords = 10;
        list.iTotalRecords = 200;
        list.aaData = personeList;

        var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(list);
        return jsonString;
    }
```

and this is the alert that I get in the browser

```
 DataTables warning: table id={id} - Ajax error
```

it appear that my webmethod is not accessible 
what should I do ???

Comment: Hi, can you move the webmethod to a separate WebService, e.g. GategoriesManagement.asmx/GetPersonList? And is 'Gategories' a typo, should it read 'Categories' or 'GetCategories'?

Comment: I need to use it as it's aspx.  when  I use it in a simple ajax call it work fine and I get my Json data so I need to know if there is some thing that was modified in .net 4.5

Comment: And is your json data matching the required format (https://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data), i.e. does it look like this (https://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data)?

Comment: when I call  my method from PageMethods it return exactly this format but when I call it throw datatables it return a full html page.I add 
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json,UseHttpGet = true)]  tag to the web method but in vain .

Answer (score 1):

The magic piece of code which makes this work as of 1.10.12 is the `ajax` parameter. ASP.NET wraps JSON results in the `.d` property, so you need to execute the callback on that object.

```
    $('#tableId').dataTable(
    {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "stateSave": false,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 30, 100, -1], [10, 30, 100, "All"]],  // 1st = page length values, 2nd = displayed options
        ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/UserService.asmx/GetUsers",
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function (data) {
                    $spinner.hide();
                    callback(data.d); // execute the callback function on the wrapped data
                }
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I really liked **@Echilon** answer, but I'd like to add that it's possible to send the Ajax request as **GET** too.

Having said that, and although OP's example didn't include a parameter in the `GetPersonList()` method, I'd like to show how parameters would need to be sent on an Ajax request depending if it's a **GET** or POST** request:

> **POST request**

It doesn't matter if the value is of type **int**, **string**, **boolean** or an **object**, the way to send data is the same that **@Echilon** showed. Although here's a little variation:

```
data: function (data) {

    data.parameterName = value;
    return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

And here's a brief example. Let's suppose that this is your original method:

```
[WebMethod]
//The parameter could be a int, string or bool
public static string GetPersonList(int|string|bool value)
{
    //do something here...
}
```

And in your Ajax call:

```
$('#tableId').dataTable(
{
    //your DataTable options here
    $.ajax({
        url: "/UserService.asmx/GetUsers",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //dataType: "json", only include this if you're expecting the result in json format
        data: function (data) {

            data.value = 10|"Test"|false; //Send the appropriate data according to the parameter type in your method
            return JSON.stringify(data);
        },
        dataSrc: "d.data" //DON'T forget to include this or your table won't load the data
    },
    // your columns settings here
});
```

In case you need to send an **object** here's a brief example. Let's suppose that this is your original method:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static string GetPersonList(Person person)
{
    //do something here...
}
```

Then in your Ajax call:

```
var $person = {};
$person.Id = 9;
$person.UserName = "jsmith";

$('#tableId').dataTable(
{
    //your DataTable options here
    $.ajax({
        url: "/UserService.asmx/GetUsers",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //dataType: "json", only include this if you're expecting the result in json format
        data: function (data) {

            data.person = $person;
            return JSON.stringify(data);
        },
        dataSrc: "d.data" //DON'T forget to include this or your table won't load the data
    },
    // your columns settings here
});
```

> **GET request**

If you prefer to use a GET request, then the way to send the data varies a little. If the value is of type **int** or **boolean**, you can send it like this:

```
data: function (data) {

    data.parameterName = value;
    return data;
}
```

But if you want to send a **string** or an **object**, then you can send it like this:

```
data: function (data) {

    data.parameterName = JSON.stringify(value);
    return data;
}
```

Let's see a brief example. Let's suppose that this is your original method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)] // I didn't include the ResponseFormat parameter because its default value is json
//The parameter could be a int or bool
public static string GetPersonList(int|bool value)
{
    //do something here...
}
```

And in your Ajax call:

```
$('#tableId').dataTable(
{
    //your DataTable options here
    $.ajax({
        url: "/UserService.asmx/GetUsers",
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //dataType: "json", only include this if you're expecting the result in json format
        data: function (data) {

            data.value = 10|false; //Send the appropriate data according to the parameter type in your method
            return data;
    },
        dataSrc: "d.data" //DON'T forget to include this or your table won't load the data
    },
    // your columns settings here
});
```

In case you need to send a **string** or an **object** here's a brief example. Let's suppose that this is your original method:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)] // I didn't include the ResponseFormat parameter because its default value is json
//The parameter could be an object or a string
public static string GetPersonList(Person person) // or (string value)
{
    //do something here...
}
```

Then in your Ajax call:

```
var $person = {};
$person.Id = 9;
$person.UserName = "jsmith";

$('#tableId').dataTable(
{
    //your DataTable options here
    $.ajax({
        url: "/UserService.asmx/GetUsers",
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //dataType: "json", only include this if you're expecting the result in json format
        data: function (data) {

            data.person = JSON.stringify($country);
            //data.value = JSON.stringify("Test"); Or this one, depending the parameter of your method
            return data;
    },
        dataSrc: "d.data" //DON'T forget to include this or your table won't load the data
    },
    // your columns settings here
});
```